# What is the purpose of signing Firefox extensions?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Signing_a_XPI) on how to sign Firefox XPI files. Why does this need to be done?

Comment: The page you read is outdated. It has no relationship to what you need to do now in order to sign an XPI for use in Firefox. It is about self-signing an extension. You need Mozilla to sign the extension, not yourself. See [Signing and distributing your add-on](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Distribution) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

The link you have is outdated. Forget everything you read there.

---

Extensions need to be sign for security reasons, to prevent add-ons that contain malicious code.

For example, someone could create an extension they say is an *Ad Blocker*, but it really collects all your passwords, and logs all your Credit Card details, then sends it back to them. When you install this add-on, you have no way of knowing what it does, without viewing the source code.

Firefox gives a warning when you install an extension that has not been signed, it says something along the lines of *This extensions has not been verified. Proceed with cation...*

Starting in Firefox 46, all extensions **must** be signed (currently there is an option to disable it in `about:config`)

Now, if that same person wants someone to install the add-on, they need to sign it (otherwise Firefox will give an error, stating that it needs to be signed). When they try and get it signed, the automated code validator or the person reviewing the code will spot what it does, and it will not get signed.

So in conclusion, the reason they are signed is for user protection.

You can read more about the process on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Distribution#Signing_your_add-on)